# How to loop through multiple Lists and create another list with merging of unique values from both the lists using Java 8 lambda expressions

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream, distinct-values

I am writing a code to loop through multiple Lists and create another list with merging of unique values from both the lists using Java 8 lambda expressions.

Model class:

```
class ServiceMap{
    Integer serviceMapId;
    Integer seviceId;
}
```

Code logic:

```
List<ServiceMap> listA = getServiceMaps();//Will get from database
List<Integer> listB = Arrays.asList(1, 10, 9);//Will get from client
List<ServiceMap> listC = new ArrayList<>();//Building it merging of both lists above

listA.stream().forEach(e -> {
    if (listB.parallelStream().noneMatch(x -> x == e.getServiceId())) {
        listC.add(new ServiceMap(e.getServiceId()));
        return;
    }

    listB.stream().forEach(x -> {
        if (listC.stream().anyMatch(e2->e2.getServiceId() == x)) {
            return;
        }
        if (x == e.getServiceId()) {
            listC.add(new ServiceMap(e.getServiceId()));
        } else {
            listC.add(new ServiceMap(x));
        }
    });

});
listC.stream().forEach(x -> System.out.println(x));
```

Is it efficient way writing code using java lambda expressions?

Comment: `Stream.of(listA, listB).map(Collection::stream).reduce(Stream.empty(), Stream::concat).distinct().collect(Collectors.toList())`. Your solution is certainly not correct.

Comment: isn't this better ? `Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>(listA);
        listB.stream().filter(i -> !set.contains(i)).forEach(set::add);`

Comment: @BoristheSpider this has horrible performance though...

Comment: Horrible performance @Eugene? Don't see why - it just whacks the whole lot into a `Set`. `reduce` with `concat` on `Stream` is the best approach - although admittedly with two lists it can be done easier; I assumed it had 3 when I wrote it. But at least it's extensible...

Comment: Updated code with actual one. Please suggest

Comment: @BoristheSpider I actually misread your code, my bad. A minor improvement for you version could be `Stream.of(listA, listB)
                .map(List::stream)
                .reduce(Stream::concat)
                .orElse(Stream.empty())
                .distinct()
                .collect(Collectors.toList());` but, still, why not `Stream.concat(listA, listB)` directly...

Comment: @Krish you posted code, received comments and answers that we took time over - reading and understanding your code and posting. Changing your code after the fact is not acceptable. Please roll back your edit.

Comment: @Eugene honestly? Because I wrote it with 3 lists first, realised there were 2, edited one out - didn't think to simply it and now it's too late...

Comment: @BoristheSpider valid arguments, happened to me quite a few times too...

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 3):

You could stream each list, apply `distinct` to them, and collect:

```
List<Integer> result = 
    Stream.concat(listA.stream(), listB.stream())
          .distinct()
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use also like this ;

```
Stream<Integer> streamOfServiceMapIds = listA.stream().map(ServiceMap::getSeviceId);
List<ServiceMap> collectedList = Stream.concat(streamOfServiceMapIds, listB.stream())
        .distinct()
        .map(ServiceMap::new)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```